# Removing chaining promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, chaining, method-chaining

New to react-native and at the moment I'm working on chaining promises.

```
myFunction(human, destination = null) {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { onRefresh } = navigation.state.params;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    return PeopleService.closeService(
      human.humanId,
      destinationPoint && destinationPoint.humanId,
    )
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          PeopleHelperService.refreshInfo().then(() => {
            if (onRefresh) {
              onRefresh();
            }
            navigation.popToTop();
            PopUp.showSuccess(
              "Success message",
            );
          });
        }
        PopUp.showError(
          "Failing message",
        );
        return null;
      })
      .finally(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Things that I want to achieve is removing chain responsibility and make it simple without chaining.

Could anyone guide me on how can I achieve this? Links to some documentation and other source will be very helpful for me to understand how to make it.

**UPDATE:**
Seems to be the answer with async/await working.

Comment: There is possibility a problem in your code logic. If `PeopleService.closeService()` promise resolve a truthy `result`, then two popups will be showed. I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want using promise then using async await. Here it is.

```
myFunction = async (human, destination = null) => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { onRefresh } = navigation.state.params;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    let result = await PeopleService.closeService(
      human.humanId,
      destinationPoint && destinationPoint.humanId,
    );

    if (result) {
        await PeopleHelperService.refreshInfo();
        if (onRefresh) {
            onRefresh();
        }
        navigation.popToTop();
        PopUp.showSuccess(
            "Success message",
        );
    }
    PopUp.showError(
        "Failing message",
    );
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
}
```

Comment: need to add `try-catch` for the finally block.

Comment: im already trying async/await, hoping it will helps, but it is only create infinite loading  when im press on button of closeSevice.

Comment: @AZ_ try-catch ? how it can help? just asking, because im interested in to understand things :)

Comment: @somerk the code inside the finally block of promise must be executed even if an error is thrown, which will not happen if try-catch blocks are not included with `async-await`.

Comment: @AZ_ now infinite loading is gone but my popUps seems to be don't want shows up

Comment: @somerk I am not sure about that, you can edit your question with the popup issue, or create a new one. and try to  debug the logged errors.

Comment: @somerk you must make sure your PeopleService.closeService and PeopleHelperService.refreshInfo() always call promise resolve. popup not showing probably cause by called function never call promise resolve.

Comment: @WilliamGunawan yes, im got your point, but in my case im trying make without promise resolve in my PeopleHelperService.refreshInfo because im using promise resolve to handle another most important things like payments.

Comment: @somerk then you can setTimeOut in certain time will always promise resolve. maybe this trick can solve your problem so your function will always resolve the promise. i'm not sure what do you mean "i'm using promise resolve to handle another *" if it not effect your popup result. you can resolve first and the async like payment will still run on the background.

Comment: @WilliamGunawan sounds like good idea. I will try this, thanks!